Index in caption (of figure) and multiple index (splitindex) and tex4ebook yield to problem
The following MWE shows the error in the resulting epub: In the figure captions the index entry within the figure caption is not correctly set in the epub.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage[texindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,title=Sachregister,name=Sachregister]
\makeindex[program=texindy,title=Namenregister,name=Namenregister]

\begin{document}
    
Please refer to figure \ref{FigA} and to figure \ref{FigB} on page \pageref{FigB}.
\begin{figure}
\caption{Captiontext for\protect\index[Namenregister]{Indexentry for figure A} figure A}\label{FigA}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

Please refer to figure \ref{FigB} and to figure \ref{FigA} on page \pageref{FigA}.
\begin{figure}
\caption{Captiontext\protect\index[Sachregister]{Indexentry fig B} for figure B}\label{FigB}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\listoffigures

\printindex[Namenregister]
\printindex[Sachregister]

\end{document}

Can this be resolved? Thanks so much.

Thank you for answering. The "error message" is not an error, but the result in the epub shows, that the code \index[Sachregister]{Something for the index} is partly found in the caption text with the presentation of the caption in the epub, so it seems clear that the index[Sachre.. is not properly processed.

@cfr The link above is 9 years old, I think this is meanwhile included in tex4ht. And it does not address \caption{\protect\index{..}}. I think that this is still missing in tex4ht. I hope of get help from the designer of it.

You haven't said why you want to put an index inside the caption. Why do you want the entry to also point to the list of figures?

@cfr Yes. The project is a translation from an original language, and in the original book some index entries point to the figures respectively captions. It is much more sophistication than latex is nowadays able to fullfull. Since these index entries are name "fig x.y" in the index entry, with a page number of the index entries apearance within the whole text. So far I don't go at the moment, I just would want to have an index in the caption, that is also to be found in the original text, which points to the figure (respectively page number of the figure caption appearance).

TeX4ht saves \index commands inside of \caption and prints them afterward. This is needed because of fatal errors that happen sometimes otherwise. It expects the usual \index command, which doesn't have an optional argument, which fails with the variant of \index provided by the Index package. We need to change the saving code to support optional arguments. This version of index.4ht should support it:
% index.4ht (2024-04-07-07:55), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1999-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-04-07-07:55}

\ifx \a:makeindex\:UnDef
   \NewConfigure{makeindex}{1} \Configure{makeindex}{}
\fi

\expandafter\ifx \csname @vwritefile\endcsname\relax
  \pend:defII\@wrindex{\warn:idx{##1}\title:chs{\html:addr
   \hbox{\Link-{}{x\last:haddr}\EndLink}}{}%
   \edef\:temp{\write\@auxout{%
      \string\@writefile{##1}{\expandafter\string\a:idxmake{\RefFileNumber
         \FileNumber}{\title:chs{x\last:haddr}{\cur:th
         \:currentlabel}}{\a:makeindex}}}}\:temp
}
\pend:def\printindex{\def\indexname{\the\@nameuse{idxtitle@\@indextype}}}
\def\warn:idx#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx \csname #1warn:idx\endcsname\relax
     \expandafter\global
         \expandafter\let \csname #1warn:idx\endcsname\def
     \:warning{If not done so, the index is to be processed by
      ^^J\space\space tex '\string\def\string\filename
         {{\jobname}{\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\idx:extI \csname idx@#1\endcsname//%
}{4dx}%
          {\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\idx:extII \csname idx@#1\endcsname//%
}} \noexpand
             \input\space idxmake.4ht'
      ^^J\space\space  makeindex -o
         \jobname.\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\idx:extII \csname idx@#1\endcsname//%
\space \jobname.4dx
      ^^Jinstead of
      ^^J\space\space  makeindex -o
         \jobname.\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\idx:extII \csname idx@#1\endcsname//%
\space
         \jobname.\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\idx:extI \csname idx@#1\endcsname//%
%
      ^^JOn some platforms, the quotation marks ' should be
      ^^J      replaced by double quotation marks " or eliminated.
     }%
     {\Configure{Needs}{File: #1.4idx}\Needs{}}%
  \fi}
\bgroup
\@ifpackageloaded{imakeidx}{
   \expandafter\gdef\csname idx:extI\endcsname#1{#1}
   \expandafter\gdef\csname idx:extII\endcsname#1{#1}
}{
   \catcode`\:=12
   \expandafter\gdef\csname idx:extI\endcsname#1:#2//{#1}
   \expandafter\gdef\csname idx:extII\endcsname#1:#2:#3//{#2}
}

\egroup


\else
  \pend:defII\@wrindex{\warn:idx{##1}\title:chs{\html:addr
   \hbox{\Link-{}{x\last:haddr}\EndLink}}{}%
   \edef\:temp{\write\@auxout{%
      \string\@vwritefile{##1}{\expandafter\string\a:idxmake{\RefFileNumber
         \FileNumber}{\title:chs{x\last:haddr}{\cur:th
         \:currentlabel}}{\a:makeindex}}}}\:temp
}

\fi

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\:saveindex[2][]{\seq_gput_right:Nn\:savedindex{[#1]{#2}}}
\def\:printsavedindex{\seq_map_inline:Nn\:savedindex{\typeout{****** ##1}\index##1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\Hinput{index}
\endinput

The important change that adds optional argument support is this:
\renewcommand\:saveindex[2][]{\seq_gput_right:Nn\:savedindex{[#1]{#2}}}
\def\:printsavedindex{\seq_map_inline:Nn\:savedindex{\typeout{****** ##1}\index##1}}

This is the result:



Thank you so much, Michal. It works! The code of the optionalized index command for multiple indexing in caption text is now only code and not text within the caption. And the index wording links in the epub point consequently into the text at the intended space. At least what I tested. Great.
